# Null client in OAuth2 Multi-Factor Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

Complete code for a Spring OAuth2 implementation of multi-factor authentication has been uploaded to [a file sharing site that you can download by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/nal2OlUqVpMFzMgqeplw). Instructions below explain how to use the link to recreate the current problem on any computer.

**THE CURRENT ERROR:**

An error is being triggered when a user tries to authenticate using two factor authentication in [the Spring Boot OAuth2 app from the link in the preceding paragraph](https://jumpshare.com/v/nal2OlUqVpMFzMgqeplw). The error is thrown at the point in the process when the app should serve up a second page asking the user for a pin code to confirm the user's identity.

Given that a null client is triggering this error, the problem seems to be how to connect a `ClientDetailsService` to a `Custom OAuth2RequestFactory` in Spring Boot OAuth2.

The [entire debug log can be read at a file sharing site by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/8BMxbxWd2SsiVmS2Yl1I).  The complete stack trace in the logs contains only one reference to code that is actually in the app, and that line of code is:

```
AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest =  
oAuth2RequestFactory.createAuthorizationRequest(paramsFromRequest(request));
```

The error thrown in the debug logs is:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.NoSuchClientException:  
No client with requested id: null
```

**CONTROL FLOW WHEN ERROR IS THROWN:**

I created the following flowchart to illustrate the intended flow of multi-factor authentication requests in [@James' suggested implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319666/two-factor-authentication-with-spring-security-oauth2#31425986):

[image]

In the preceding flowchart, the current error is being thrown at some point between the **Username & Password View** and the **GET /secure/two_factor_authenticated** steps.

**The solution to this OP is limited in scope to the FIRST PASS that 1.) travels through the `/oauth/authorize` endpoint and then 2.) returns back to the `/oauth/authorize` endpoint via `TwoFactorAuthenticationController`.**

So we simply want to resolve the `NoSuchClientException` while also demonstrating that the client has been successfully granted `ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED` in the `POST /secure/two_factor_authenticated`.  Given that the subsequent steps are boiler-plate, it is acceptable for the flow to demonstrably break in the **SECOND PASS** entry into `CustomOAuth2RequestFactory`, as long as the user enters the **SECOND PASS** with all the artifacts of successfully having completed the **FIRST PASS**.  The **SECOND PASS** can be a separate question as long as we successfully resolve the **FIRST PASS** here.

**RELEVANT CODE EXCERPTS:**

Here is the code for the `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`, where I attempt to set up the connection:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired//ADDED AS A TEST TO TRY TO HOOK UP THE CUSTOM REQUEST FACTORY
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired//Added per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319666/two-factor-authentication-with-spring-security-oauth2
    private CustomOAuth2RequestFactory customOAuth2RequestFactory;

    //THIS NEXT BEAN IS A TEST
    @Bean CustomOAuth2RequestFactory customOAuth2RequestFactory(){
        return new CustomOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
                    new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "foobar".toCharArray()
                )
                .getKeyPair("test");
        converter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("acme")//API: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/builders/ClientDetailsServiceBuilder.ClientBuilder.html
                    .secret("acmesecret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password")
                    .scopes("openid");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints//API: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configurers/AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer.html
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter())
            .requestFactory(customOAuth2RequestFactory);//Added per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319666/two-factor-authentication-with-spring-security-oauth2
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer//API: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configurers/AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.html
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the `TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter`, which contains the code above that is triggering the error:

```
package demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.AuthorizationRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2RequestFactory;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

//This class is added per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319666/two-factor-authentication-with-spring-security-oauth2
/**
 * Stores the oauth authorizationRequest in the session so that it can
 * later be picked by the {@link com.example.CustomOAuth2RequestFactory}
 * to continue with the authoriztion flow.
 */
public class TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
    private OAuth2RequestFactory oAuth2RequestFactory;
    //These next two are added as a test to avoid the compilation errors that happened when they were not defined.
    public static final String ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED = "ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED";
    public static final String ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED = "ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED";

    @Autowired
    public void setClientDetailsService(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        oAuth2RequestFactory = new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService);
    }

    private boolean twoFactorAuthenticationEnabled(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return authorities.stream().anyMatch(
            authority -> ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED.equals(authority.getAuthority())
    );
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Check if the user hasn't done the two factor authentication.
        if (AuthenticationUtil.isAuthenticated() && !AuthenticationUtil.hasAuthority(ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED)) {
            AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = oAuth2RequestFactory.createAuthorizationRequest(paramsFromRequest(request));
            /* Check if the client's authorities (authorizationRequest.getAuthorities()) or the user's ones
               require two factor authenticatoin. */
            if (twoFactorAuthenticationEnabled(authorizationRequest.getAuthorities()) ||
                    twoFactorAuthenticationEnabled(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities())) {
                // Save the authorizationRequest in the session. This allows the CustomOAuth2RequestFactory
                // to return this saved request to the AuthenticationEndpoint after the user successfully
                // did the two factor authentication.
               request.getSession().setAttribute(CustomOAuth2RequestFactory.SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, authorizationRequest);

                // redirect the the page where the user needs to enter the two factor authentiation code
                redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response,
                        ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                            .path(TwoFactorAuthenticationController.PATH)
                            .toUriString());
                return;
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private Map<String, String> paramsFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : request.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
            params.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()[0]);
        }
        return params;
    }
}
```

**RE-CREATING THE PROBLEM ON YOUR COMPUTER:**

You can recreate the problem on any computer in only a few minutes by following these simple steps:

1.) Download the [zipped version of the app from a file sharing site by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/nal2OlUqVpMFzMgqeplw).

2.) Unzip the app by typing: `tar -zxvf oauth2.tar(1).gz`

3.) launch the `authserver` app by navigating to `oauth2/authserver` and then typing `mvn spring-boot:run`.

4.) launch the `resource` app by navigating to `oauth2/resource` and then typing `mvn spring-boot:run`

5.) launch the `ui` app by navigating to `oauth2/ui` and then typing `mvn spring-boot:run`

6.) Open a web browser and navigate to `http : // localhost : 8080`

7.) Click `Login` and then enter `Frodo` as the user and `MyRing` as the password, and click to submit.  **This will trigger the error shown above.**

You can view the complete source code by:

a.) importing the maven projects into your IDE, or by

b.) navigating within the unzipped directories and opening with a text editor.

Note:  The code in the file sharing link above is a combination of [the Spring Boot OAuth2 GitHub sample at this link](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2), and the [suggestions for 2 Factor Authentication offered by @James at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319666/two-factor-authentication-with-spring-security-oauth2#31425986).  The only changes to the Spring Boot GitHub sample have been in the `authserver` app, specifically in [`authserver/src/main/java`](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main) and in [`authserver/src/main/resources/templates`](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main).

**NARROWING THE PROBLEM:**

Per @AbrahamGrief's suggestion, I added a `FilterConfigurationBean`, which resolved the `NoSuchClientException`.  But the OP asks how to complete the **FIRST PASS** through the control flow in the diagram.

I then narrowed the problem by setting `ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED` in `Users.loadUserByUername()` as follows:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    String password;
    List<GrantedAuthority> auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
    if (username.equals("Samwise")) {//ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED will need to come from the resource, NOT the user
        auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_HOBBIT, ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED");
        password = "TheShire";
    }
    else if (username.equals("Frodo")){//ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED will need to come from the resource, NOT the user
        auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_HOBBIT, ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED");
        password = "MyRing";
    }
    else{throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username was not found. ");}
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, password, auth);
}
```

This eliminates the need to configure clients and resources, so that the current problem remains narrow.  However, the next roadblock is that Spring Security is rejecting the user's request for `/security/two_factor_authentication`.  **What further changes need to be made to complete the FIRST PASS through the control flow, so that the `POST /secure/two_factor_authentication` can SYSO `ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a *lot* of modifications needed for that project to implement the described flow, more than should be in scope for a single question.  This answer will focus solely on how to resolve:

> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.NoSuchClientException: No
>   client with requested id: null

when trying to use a `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` and a `Filter` bean while running in a Spring Boot authorization server.

The reason this exception is happening is because [`WebApplicationInitializer` instances are *not* run by Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/321).  That includes any `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` subclasses that would work in a WAR deployed to a standalone Servlet container.  So what is happening is Spring Boot creates your filter because of the `@Bean` annotation, ignores your `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`, and applies your filter to all URLs.  Meanwhile, you only want your filter applied to those URLs that you're trying to pass to `addMappingForUrlPatterns`.

Instead, to apply a servlet Filter to particular URLs in Spring Boot, you should [define a `FilterConfigurationBean`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30658752/2646526).  For the flow described in the question, which is trying to apply a custom `TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter` to `/oauth/authorize`, that would look as follows:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean twoFactorAuthenticationFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(twoFactorAuthenticationFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/oauth/authorize");
    registration.setName("twoFactorAuthenticationFilter");
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter twoFactorAuthenticationFilter() {
    return new TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter();
}
```

Comment: This is not a 500 point answer yet, but moves us forward. I agree we should narrow scope, so I narrowed the remaining problem by setting the user's roles in Users.`loadUserByUserName()` like `else if (username.equals("Frodo")){ auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_HOBBIT, ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED"); password = "MyRing";}`. However, `/secure/two_factor_authentication` is not open to `ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED`. How do I get it so that the user's password check results in their getting access to '/secure/two_factor_authentication'? +1 so far

Comment: I added something to the end of the OP narrowing the problem.

Comment: @CodeMed As a few more steps forward, in `AuthserverApplication`, replace `.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")` with `.and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/secure/two_factor_authentication", "/pincode").authenticated()`, add `.authorities(TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter.ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED)` to your ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer,  and in `TwoFactorAuthenticationController` return `"pinCode"` instead of `"templates/pinCode"`.

Comment: The scope of the OP is resolved now, after fixing a couple downstream typos.  It is currently giving an `Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token` error after completing most of the **SECOND PASS** in the control flow chart in the OP.  This means that the requirements for this bounty have been met.  What I appreciate most is that you replied early in the bounty period, so that I did not have to wait the entire seven days.  Thank you and +525.

Comment: @turgos I don't have it.